# Is it possible to find in an html page what modification codes are used by whole css file?

Tags: html, css

If i have a css file with a lot of modification codes, is it any webpage or developer tool that can recognize loading a page, what css codes are used?

Comment: yes, on every browser examiner ( F12 )

Comment: I know the inspect element choice...More especially, to take a css file and giving the relative html page to give you totally all information about css that is active and css that is not....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using the **code coverage** functionality that is part of chrome developer tools. Please find the link below to explore more. In a nut shell, it will give you an idea of how much percentage of the code, css/js is used by you application. In your case with css, it can give you which classes are not used.

You can find more details here in the [Chrome Official Documentation](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/devtools-release-notes#coverage) or in this [blog](https://www.vojtechruzicka.com/measuring-javascript-and-css-coverage-with-google-chrome-developer-tools/).

Comment: Thanks for your advice...I didnt know that was possible that with Google Chrome!!!